# How to add custom image to each of the multiple facebook share buttons? I have multiple share buttons in single page

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-like, facebook-sharer

I have tried og:image meta tag as given here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-button. This seem to support one image for one page, and facebook seem to be assuming that you need one share button in one html page.

Also, a similar looking question - [Multiple Facebook, Twitter share buttons in one page with custom image and title](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29095897/multiple-facebook-twitter-share-buttons-in-one-page-with-custom-image-and-title) does not answer custom image to each of the multiple share buttons in page. Here's how I'm adding og:image for each insertion. Below snippet is in the loop.

Thanks a ton for the help in advance.

```html
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                      
                        <% @map_url = ('http://maps.google.com/?q='.to_s + @user.address.to_s) %>
                        <small><%= link_to @user.address, @map_url, target: "_blank", style: 'color:#0645AD;' %>
                        </small>

                        <% @facebook_comment_url = ('https://wobbleapp.in/users/'.to_s + @user.id.to_s) %>
                        <meta property="fb:app_id" content="XXXXXXXXXX" />
                        <meta property="og:url" content= <% @facebook_comment_url%> />
                        <meta property="og:image" content="https://d2l5nbch64gdxx.cloudfront.net/uploads/user/image/47287/upload_image.jpeg" />
                        <meta property="og:description" content="Potholes in your locality!" />

                        <div class="fb-like pt-2" 
                        data-href= <%= @facebook_comment_url %>
                        data-layout="standard" data-action="like" data-size="small" data-show-faces="true" data-share="true"></div>

                        <div 
                            class="fb-comments" 
                            data-href= <%= @facebook_comment_url %> ></div>

                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: Correct. One URL = one image. Just share different unique URLs and set the right og:image for each of them

Comment: @WizKid I have added unique url for each share button using data-href tag in as 
<div class="fb-like pt-2" 
                        data-href= http://unique_comment_url >
                        data-layout="standard" data-action="like" data-size="small" data-show-faces="true" data-share="true"></div>

Not sure how og:image meta tag can be added to each share button. Could you please give an example?

Comment: Well you need an HTML document for each such URL, that contains the relevant OG meta data ...

Comment: @CBroe Here's the single page web - www.wobbleapp.in. Any idea on how can we have html document for each url when all images, share buttons, urls are infact present in the same page? Thanks!

Comment: By creating those HTML documents …?

Comment: @CBroe I have added the piece through which I'm adding og:image for each share button. Not working.

Comment: That’s not how it works, the like button does not take a picture “parameter”.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/140171/discussion-between-anubhav16-and-cbroe).

Answer (score 0):

You need to have one webpage (eg. http://example.com/) to have the FB share button script and html tags, as per [Multiple Facebook, Twitter share buttons in one page with custom image and title](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29095897/multiple-facebook-twitter-share-buttons-in-one-page-with-custom-image-and-title)

Then you need each image webpage (eg. http://example.com/image/1) to have the Open Graph meta tags, as per https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/opengraph/using-objects#objectapi

You do **not** put the `<meta property="...">` tags on the same page as the FB share button script and tags.  This is what WizKid and CBroe were trying to explain in the comments.